# Convert: "preg_replace" -> "preg_replace_callback"

Tags: url-rewriting, preg-replace, deprecated, preg-replace-callback

I'm trying to update my code but I'm stuck at this codeline.

How do I proceed to convert this to preg_replace_callback?

```
$buffer = preg_replace("#§([a-z0-9-_]+)\.?([a-z0-9-_]+)?#ie","\$templ->\\1(\\2)",$buffer);
```

Comment: Hello!  Can you please show me an example of what you are trying to do here?  Converting is pretty straightforward and I can get you a code example if you can shed some more light on what the string looks like and what you expect it to look like after you are finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the process of converting `preg_replace` (with the `e` modifier) to `preg_replace_callback`.  You create a function that will act on all of the matches that it finds.  Normally this is pretty simple, however with your case it is a little more complex as the function returns the value of an object.  To accommodate this, you can use an anonymous function (a function without a name) and attach the `USE` keyword with your object to it.  This can be done inline, however for the sake of clarity, I have made it its own variable.

Take a look at this portion of the complete code below:

```
$callback_function = function($m) use ($templ) {
```

I created a variable named `callback_function` that will be used in the `preg_replace_callback` function.  This function will be fed each match as the variable `$m` automatically.  So within the function you can use `$m[1]` and `$m[2]` to access the parts of the expression that it matched.  Also note that I've attached the `$templ` variable with the `USE` keyword so that `$templ` will be available within the function.

Hopefully that makes sense.  Anyway, here is the complete code:

```
<?php

// SET THE TEXT OF THE BUFFER STRING
$buffer = 'There are a bunch of §guns.roses growing along the side of the §guns.road.';

// THIS IS JUST A SAMPLE CLASS SINCE I DO NOT KNOW WHAT YOUR CLASS REALLY LOOKS LIKE
class Test {

    // FUNCTION NAMED 'guns' WITH A SPACE FOR A PARAMETER
    public function guns($info) {
        return '<b>BLUE '.strtoupper($info).'</b>';
    }

}

// INSTANTIATE A NEW 'Test' CLASS
$templ = new Test();

// THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT YOUR CALLBACK WILL USE
// NOTICE THAT IT IS AN ANONYMOUS FUNCTION (THERE IS NO FUNCTION NAME)
$callback_function = function($m) use ($templ) {
    return $templ->$m[1]($m[2]);
};

// THIS USES PREG_REPLACE_CALLBACK TO SUBSTITUTE OUT THE MATCHED TEXT WITH THE CALLBACK FUNCTION
$buffer = preg_replace_callback('/§([a-z0-9-_]+)\.?([a-z0-9-_]+)?/i', $callback_function, $buffer);

// PRINT OUT THE FINAL VERSION OF THE STRING
print $buffer;
```

This outputs the following:

```
There are a bunch of <b>BLUE ROSES</b> growing along the side of the <b>BLUE ROAD</b>.
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this very soon and give you the proper response!

Comment: It worked fine and thank you for the detailed explanation! much love my friend! <3